# Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin for CROS

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, web, cors

I'm developping a spring mvc rest api. I added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response.

With PostMan, I found the header like this :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server →Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

But when I test it with a *test.html*, it shows error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/tokens. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I don't know why because by Postman, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is already there. Maybe it's the problem of `application/json`?

Ajax part :

```
function tokens_Post(username,password){

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/tokens",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType : "application/json",
        data:{username:username,password:password},
        success:show_user_info,
        error:checkError
    });

}
```

Server code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = RestURIConstants.TOKEN_POST, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Token> TokenPOST(
        @RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rp) {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    ResponseEntity<Token> response = 
            restTemplate.postForEntity(Token_post_url, user, Token.class);

    rp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    rp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");

    response = new ResponseEntity<Token>(response.getBody(), HttpStatus.OK);
    System.out.println(response.getBody().toString());

    return response;

}
```

The server code, it uses another rest api.

Converter

```
<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Can you show your ajax call code in test.html?

Comment: @WornOutSoles I added it. It's a simple function for getting a token.

Comment: @GGrec Thank you, but I prefer you like this question XDD. I stopped here for two days. No ideas

Answer (score 1):

Add `crossDomain : true` in your ajax attribute

Also change like this `data:JSON.stringify({username:username,password:password}),`

Comment: change json to jsonp in the dataType

Comment: Maybe it's because it's Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*. with "→" not ":"? @Bharath

Comment: Are you trying to do a JSON post?

Comment: Now it's Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Méthode Non Autorisée), maybe i need to update my rest api.

Comment: Yes. It's a json post. It's here the problem?

Comment: then add contentType : "application/json" and get the value is server from request body

Comment: Thank you Bharath. But still it's a 405 error : GET http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/tokens?callback=jQuery1111022640165546908975_1403599106995&username=WZZZ9304&password=Ab07180363%3F&_=1403599106996 405 (Méthode Non Autorisée)

Comment: Do that server is having httpmessageconverter configured in the xml

Comment: Yes, MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. I test it with PostMan, it works well.

Comment: Remove those crossDomain and 'jsonp' as it is JSON post

Comment: I delete them. It's so strange, why XMLRequestHttp can not find the header.

Comment: Does the request went through?

Comment: Always the same thing. Ok with PostMan. But with ajax, always No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I guess the problem with HttpHeaders. remove it and add HttpServletRequest request and HttpServletResponse response to the method arguments. then set headers like    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET"); response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

Comment: thank you very much. I worte a new one with HttpServlet, but still the same. The browser said "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8090/rest/v1/tokens. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access." But with PostMan, it works. ToT

Comment: dont use HttpServlet, use HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in method arguments....... public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Token> TokenPOST(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

Comment: I added like this. I can see headers in the postman so I think the problem is XMLHttpRequest. Because here the return is json type. How do you think about it? Maybe it's why json can't be used for CORS. Jsonp works only for get.